# How to allow special characters (French accent characters é,à,...) in email address fields in Salesforce?

Tags: email

Is there any way to allow French accents in email address fields in Salesforce? I browsed around and noticed it's not supported.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid not. Salesforce supports the RFC 2822 standard for email, and only allows the following characters in the part of the email before the @ sign:

```
abcdefg.hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!#$%&'*/=?^_+-`{|}~0123456789
```

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000001145&type=1

Comment: But not RFC 5336 or or RFC 5335, which would allow such possibilities.